# Alternative approaches to a Minecraft Redstone Simulator

Tags: java, graph-theory, dijkstra, minecraft

I'm just programming a Minecraft Redstone Simulator for Android.
I'm doing the simulation with some variations of Dijkstra, but I heard, that the real simulator does something different and updates every redstone block every redstone tick.

How is notch doing it?

**Update**
I know that he uses a HashSet, this doesn't look like Dijkstra, does it?

Comment: "How is notch doing it?" is probably a question more appropriate for notch and the other Minecraft devs, not SO. :P

Comment: Some people deobfustcated the minecraft code to write mods - I'm interested in notchs way, because my way is deterministic but his isn't... So I wan'T to know if there's an opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will call anything that's redstone-related a "redstone block".

Every tick, Minecraft iterates through the hashset and updates each redstone block.

When more redstone blocks are added, the hashset size is increased, and everything that was in the previous, smaller hashset is scrambled into a random order.